# Graph API error message: "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft Graph API to post messages in a specific MS Teams channels but I get the following errors:

- in Postman:
  `{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.","innerError":{"date":"2023-12-05T13:23:26","request-id":"27ff306e-d5ac-46fe-9ac5-57cde99a922d","client-request-id":"27ff306e-d5ac-46fe-9ac5-57cde99a922d"}}}`
- in the integration platform I am using:
  `{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.","innerError":{"date":"2023-12-05T13:23:26","request-id":"27ff306e-d5ac-46fe-9ac5-57cde99a922d","client-request-id":"27ff306e-d5ac-46fe-9ac5-57cde99a922d"}}}`

Although the error is slightly different, it refers to the same issue: I am not authorized to make API calls in this specific channel since, according to the link in the first error message, the call can be made only for *channels in migration state*. I am not sure I fully understand it tbh.

In Graph Explorer, the request is successful and the message is posted in the channel. It's when I try it with other tools like Postman that does not work. I guess Graph Explorer has extra authorizations in place.

Do you know any workaround on it?

I would not mind to change the state of my channel as long as I am able to post messages through API.

[image: Graph Explorer]
[image: Postman]
[image: Integration tool]
[image: permissions in MS Azure 1]
[image: permissions in MS Azure 2]

I tried to make several calls and refresh the token several times and add permissions but it works only in Graph Explorer

EDIT: The user to post messages can also be a bot or an integration user

Answer (score 0):

You are using Application permissions instead of using Delegated permissions, therefore you are getting this error. As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), Application permissions are only supported for [migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams).

Delegated permissions are used by apps that have a signed-in user present (like in the Graph Explorer). For these apps, the user authorizes the app to act as the signed-in user when making calls to Microsoft Graph. So, it is working there.

When you're using tools like Postman, you're likely using Application permissions, which means the app is running without a signed-in user present. The error message you're seeing is because the operation you're trying to perform (posting a message to a channel) requires Delegated permissions, not Application permissions.

Comment: Hi Prasad, I have enabled both permissions (Delegated and Application). I have attached a two new screenshots showing the permissions I have. Could you please share a screenshot with the list of permissions I need to enable and disable to make this work or a step-by-step guide?

Comment: These delegated permissions we need: `ChannelMessage.Send`, `Group.ReadWrite.All`. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: I already have these two delegated permissions so that should not be the problem. Is it possible that Application permissions create conflict if enabled along with delegated permissions?

Comment: That should not be a problem. As Postman uses Application permissions, you are getting this. you'll need to change your authorization method to use Delegated permissions. This will likely involve signing in as a user who has the necessary permissions to post messages to the channel.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of a sample call in Postman? Do I still use the authentication token? Also, what kind of permissions are needed in order to post messages? Sorry, I am not fully following

Comment: Use delegated authentication with Postman for Microsoft Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman-with-delegated-authentication